# How is the program using the stack here?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86, stack

For the code shown below, If I print the addresses, I get the following.

```
&test_var1 = 0x7fff0067d87c
&barrier (passed argument) = 0x7fff0067d770
&i (passed argument) = 0x7fff0067d77c
&test_var2 = 0x7fff0067d78c
```

There are two things I don't understand here. First is that I read that C pushes arguments from right to left, then how **&i** is greater than **&barrier**. Knowing that stack grows from a higher address to a lower address, **&i** should be at a lower address. Moreover, the local variable **test_var2** is at even a greater address.

Secondly, one would expect the value of **&barrier** and **&test_var1** to be close together, but no, you see a big difference of 268 bytes. What is the stack holding in between?

Note that I'm using optimization O3. Is this due to that? Maybe the compiler has played some tricks here? I use volatile to make sure every variable is on the stack here and not cached in some register.

```
void some_func()
{
.........
{
  volatile int test_var1 = 0;
}
call_func( i, &barrier );
........
}

void call_func( volatile int i, volatile pthread_barrier* barrier )
{
 volatile int test_var2 = 0;
 ........
}
```

Comment: The way the stack is used is implemented in the specific C compiler. You could look this up in the GCC source in your case.

Comment: You'd make it a lot easier for all of us if you'd include a complete example we could compile and run.

Comment: `volatile` should have no effect on the *address* of a variable. Also, you have two different types of volatile here: `volatile int` means the int itself can change, whereas `volatile whatever*` means that the "whatever" is volatile, but the pointer (i.e. the variable) is not itself volatile - the other way around would be `whatever volatile *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On x86 the stack (used when f() calls g()) grows downward.

Anyhow the way the compiler arranges the var/s for a certain call is implementation dependend.

Comment: It grows from a higher address to a lower address. For me going from a higher address to a lower address is called upwards, for you its downwards. But I wanted to say that, so yeah you are right and I too. I Edited my question to say from a higher to lower address instead of saying upwards or downwards.

Answer (score 1):

You're making a bunch of assumptions here, none of which are really warranted:

- The compiler has to push some number of registers when it calls a function; there's no rule that says they can't be in between the arguments and the local variables.
- There's no rule that the arguments have to be pushed in any particular order, or event that they are on the stack at all; arguments can be passed in registers, too.
- How memory is organized into a program stack is processor-dependent; in the x86 architecture it grows *downward*, not upwards.

Comment: "In the x86 architecture, it grows downards". That is certainly not true, because if you look at the functions in dissassembly, you will see that rsp is subtracted in the beginning of functions and added at the end. And I was actually using volatile to make sure everything is on the stack. Modified that in my question.

Comment: First link from Googling `x86 stack architecture` says otherwise: http://wiki.osdev.org/Stack#Stack_example_on_the_X86_architecture

Comment: Its the way you interpret it. By upward I meant from a higher address to lower address, which you and this link call it downward. So basically what I wanted to say is that it grows from a higher address towards lower address.

Comment: This link has some nice diagrams: http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/theory/2055-stack-architecture-demystified.html

Comment: @MetallicPriest pretty well any speaker of English uses 'downward' to mean 'from higher to lower'

Comment: @Pete, Its the way how you imagine the layout of memory. I always Imagine the lower address to be at the top. But you are right, we should call it downwards. I will be careful the next time :)!

Comment: @MetallicPriest Because of this ambiguity of diagram layout (lowaddr at the top of image or at the bottom of image), one should prefer a left-right bar where, really now, most people would agree that left is low and right is high.

Comment: @jørgensen -- Given that apparently some people associate "up" with "low" and "down" with "high", I would not make that assumption. Folks whose native language reads right-to-left, for example, would likely not agree.